# Regex and replacement

Tags: java, regex, replace, replaceall

I'm a Java beginner and already asked a similar question last week but notwithstanding your helpful answers I still haven't solved my issue, so I think I should give you the whole story. Given a text like

```
Se excluye arbitraje de ley y [rotura de lunas]Gar_1. Se excluye arbitraje de ley y [rotura de lunas]noGar.

Excluimos todas aquellas cosas que [arbitraje de ley]Gar_1.

Excluimos todas aquellas cosas que son afinidad de [Arbitraje de ley]Gar_1.
```

I want to replace the string-label 'Gar_1' by 'noGar' only for those strings that have both labels (namely '[rotura de lunas]' in the above ex.). 
The input from which I take the sentences which I check for the regex and where I eventually do the replacement is a txt file.

My code is the following:

```
public class Trial_2 {

private static String REGEX = "\\[.*\\](?=(Gar_1|noGar))";  
private static String BE_REPLACED = "Gar_1";  // def part of seq that I want to replace
private static String REPLACE = "noGar";  // def the replacement string     

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String input = readFile("corpus_pruebas_multiples_2.txt");
    System.out.println("Original input: " + input);

    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(REGEX);  // compare string seq to general pattern 
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(input);  // get a matcher object for this general pattern

    if(m1.find( )){
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m1.group(0));  
            Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(BE_REPLACED);  // compare string to pattern
            Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(input);  // get a matcher object for this pattern
            input = m2.replaceAll(REPLACE);  // replace 
            // print out new string seq with desired replacement:
            System.out.println("Replacement: " + input);  
        } else{
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }     
}


// Method that allows to read from a file by passing it the filename as a param.
      static String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {

          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

          try {
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              String line = br.readLine();  

              while(line != null) {
                  sb.append(line);  
                  sb.append("\n");
                  line = br.readLine();  
              }
              return sb.toString(); 
          } finally{
              br.close();
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: *I still haven't solved my issue* Ok, but what *is* your issue?

Comment: It's explained in full above.  I need a general way of saying "if you have [blabla]Gar_1 [blabla]noGar [bleble]Gar_1 [bleble]Gar_1, replace the Gar_1 of [blabla] with noGar leaving the Gar_1 of [bleble] unchanged". How can I make this selection?

Comment: So you are saying, if you have 2 "labels": `[x]` and `[y]`, and label `[x]` has an occurrence of *both* `Gar_1` and `noGar`, then you want to replace `Gar_1` with `noGar`. But if label `[y]` only has occurrences of `Gar_1`, then *don't* replace them with `noGar`?

Comment: Exactly! How do I do that? I've tried various things but nothing works perfectly... The code I wrote replaces ALL 'Gar_1'...

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do this solely with regex. I think you will have to scan through your string for labels and keep track of which ones have occurrences of both Gar_1 and noGar.

Comment: Is it possible for the labels with Gar_1 and noGar to be ordered differently? i.e.: can a label with noGar come *before* that same label with Gar_1? Also, can there be more than 2 occurrences of a given label?

Comment: Yes to both questions: a label with "noGar" can come before the same label with "Gar_1", and there can be multiple occurrences of a given label. How can I keep track of the occurrences of "Gar_1" and of "noGar"?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to replace the string-label `'Gar_1'` by `'noGar'` only for those strings that have both labels (namely `'[rotura de lunas]'` in the above ex.).

You can do:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\[rotura de lunas\\])Gar_1", "noGar");
```

#### [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bX8gE0)

**Edit:** To support various phrases in square brackets use this:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\[(blabla|rotura de lunas)\\])Gar_1", "noGar");
```

OR else if you want to avoid replacements for certain phrases then use **negative lookbehind**:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("(\\[(?<!bleble)[^\\]]*\\])Gar_1", "$1noGar");
```

Comment: But in this case it's just 'rotura de lunas', but in general it can be any string, so I need a general solution. I need a general way of saying "if you have [blabla]Gar_1 [blabla]noGar [bleble]Gar_1 [bleble]Gar_1, replace the Gar_1 of [blabla] with noGar leaving the Gar_1 of [bleble] unchanged". How can I make this selection?

Comment: No, not yet, because I need a more general solution, it must work for ANY given sentence, not a specific list of them...

Comment: Did you see negative lookhehind based code above? Also can you clarify about generic solution since your question and comments are not clear enough.

Comment: I mean: I have a very long txt file where some groups of words are labelled with 'Gar_1', some groups of words are labelled with 'noGar', and some are labelled with both labels. When I have a groups of words with both labels (i.e. 'Gar_1' and 'noGar'), only for this group of words, I want to replace the 'Gar_1' label by the 'noGar' label.

Comment: `When I have a groups of words with both labels (i.e. 'Gar_1' and 'noGar'),` Can you show few examples of these type of text?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using grouping feature of regex that is captured by parenthesis `()`. Here `$1` represent first matched group.

Regex pattern : `(\[rotura de lunas\])(Gar_1)`

Sample code:

```
String pattern = "(\\[rotura de lunas\\])(Gar_1)";

String str1 = "Se excluye arbitraje de ley y [rotura de lunas]Gar_1. Se excluye arbitraje de ley y [rotura de lunas]noGar.";
System.out.println(str1.replaceAll(pattern, "$1noGar"));

String str2 = "Excluimos todas aquellas cosas que son afinidad de [Arbitraje de ley]Gar_1.";
System.out.println(str2.replaceAll(pattern, "$1noGar"));
```

output:

```
Se excluye arbitraje de ley y [rotura de lunas]noGar. Se excluye arbitraje de ley y [rotura de lunas]noGar.
Excluimos todas aquellas cosas que son afinidad de [Arbitraje de ley]Gar_1.
```

here is demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/hB9tJ4)

---

If you want to add more then simply add it in the regex pattern separated by `|` that represent OR.

For e.g.

```
(\[(rotura de lunas)|(blabla)\])(Gar_1)
```

that will match `[rotura de lunas]Gar_1` and `[blabla]Gar_1`

Comment: Thanks! But this works for the simple example of 2 sentences. But I have a very long txt file where some groups of words are labelled with 'Gar_1', some groups of words are labelled with 'noGar', and some are labelled with both labels. When I have a groups of words with both labels (i.e. 'Gar_1' and 'noGar'), only for this group of words, I want to replace the 'Gar_1' label by the 'noGar' label. How can I generalize your solution to my general case?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. What I've basically done is go through the input, find each occurrence of `\\[.*\\](?=(Gar_1|noGar))`, and stick it in a set based on whether it contains `Gar_1` or `noGar`. Then I took the intersection of the two sets, so that I have a set that contains the strings that were found to have occurrences of both. Then I just replaced all occurences of each string + `Gar_1` with that same string + `noGar`.

```
public class Trial_2 {

private static String REGEX = "\\[.*\\](?=(Gar_1|noGar))";  
private static String BE_REPLACED = "Gar_1";  // def part of seq that I want to replace
private static String REPLACE = "noGar";  // def the replacement string     

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String input = readFile("corpus_pruebas_multiples_2.txt");
    System.out.println("Original input: " + input);

    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(REGEX);  // compare string seq to general pattern 
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(input);  // get a matcher object for this general pattern

    Set<String> gar1Set = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> noGarSet = new HashSet<>();
    while(m1.find( )){
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m1.group());

        String match = m1.group();
        String noLabel = match.substring(0, match.indexOf("]")+1);
        if(match.contains(BE_REPLACED)) {
            gar1Set.add(noLabel);
        }
        else {
            noGarSet.add(noLabel);
        }
    }

    gar1Set.retainAll(noGarSet);
    String replaced = "";
    for(String toReplace : gar1Set) {
        replaced = input.replace(toReplace + BE_REPLACED, toReplace + REPLACE);
    }
    // print out new string seq with desired replacement:
    System.out.println("Replacement: " + replaced);
}


// Method that allows to read from a file by passing it the filename as a param.
      static String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {

          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

          try {
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              String line = br.readLine();  

              while(line != null) {
                  sb.append(line);  
                  sb.append("\n");
                  line = br.readLine();  
              }
              return sb.toString(); 
          } finally{
              br.close();
          }
      }
}
```

*Note: I have not tested this, so there may be some bugs, but I think it gets the idea across.*